# getLonLatFromPixel not always correct / consistent

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a problem with the conversion from pixel to lon/lat. It's not always correct.
The map is a simple XYZ map. The items on it are dragable. But after I dragged an item it gives me a wrong lon/lat value. Most of the time it's 50 pixels to low.

I've created a grid on the map with lines every 100 pixels. When I move an item on the 3th line sometimes I get 300, other times 250.

Is this a bug in OpenLayers or is there something I did wrong?

```
groundplan = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
    'GroundPlan',
    '@Url.Content("~/Centrals/" + ViewBag.Id)/Maps/' + planId + '/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg',
    {
        attribution: "&copy; Limotec",
        transitionEffect: 'resize',
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(0, 0, 4096, 4096),
        maxResolution: 4096 / 256,
        numZoomLevels: 5
    }
);
map.addLayer(groundplan);

markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Markers",
    {
        renderOptions: { yOrdering: true },
        renderers: renderer
    }
);
map.addLayer(markers);

dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(markers);
dragFeature.onComplete = function (feature, pixel) {
    var id = feature.geometry.id;
    id = id.replace('Det_', '');

    //var lonLat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(pixel);
    var lonLat = groundplan.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(pixel);
    console.info("Moved detector " + id + " naar " + lonLat.lon + " - " + lonLat.lat + " (x: " + pixel.x + " y: " + pixel.y + ")");

    $.post('@Url.Action( "MoveDet", "Api" )',
        { "centralId": @ViewBag.Id, "id": id, "lat": lonLat.lon, "lng": lonLat.lat }
    );
}

dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopDown = false;
dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopUp = false;
dragFeature.handlers['drag'].stopClick = false;
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopDown = false;
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopUp = false;
dragFeature.handlers['feature'].stopClick = false; 
map.addControl(dragFeature);
dragFeature.activate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem now. Instead of using pixel and calculating the lonlat, I now use feature.geometry to get the correct position. It gives me a better result of the position of the moved object.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code for converting pixel to lonlat, I am using too(from [GDAL2Tiles](http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/) ):

```
var originShift = 2 * MATH.PI * 6378137 / 2.0
var initialResolution = 2 * MATH.PI * 6378137 / 256 // tilesize

function MetersToLatLon( mx, my ){
    //"Converts XY point from Spherical Mercator EPSG:900913 to lat/lon in WGS84 Datum"

    lon = (mx / originShift) * 180.0
    lat = (my / originShift) * 180.0

    lat = 180 / MATH.PI * (2 * MATH.atan(MATH.exp(lat * MATH.PI / 180.0)) - MATH.PI / 2.0)
    return lat, lon
};

function Resolution(self, zoom ){
    //"Resolution (meters/pixel) for given zoom level (measured at Equator)"

    return self.initialResolution / (2**zoom)
};    

function PixelsToMeters( px, py, zoom){
    //"Converts pixel coordinates in given zoom level of pyramid to EPSG:900913"

    res = Resolution(zoom)
    mx = px * res - originShift
    my = py * res - originShift
    return mx, my
};
```

now use this method to get right pixeltolonlat:

```
MetersToLatLon(PixelsToMeters( px, py, zoom));
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: It doesn't work. The pixel value is relative to the viewport. It is different when the map is panned.

Comment: what error did you take when you have executed mentioned method?

Comment: The result is completly wrong. It's negative. The result has to be between 0 and 4096 (the size of the map)

Comment: My map has no projection. So what I need is the correct possition of the object I moved on the map. From the DragFeature I get the position relative to the viewport. Using map.getLonLatFromPixel gives me sometimes the wrong result because when refreshing the page puts the object on the wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just needed the right position of first point of a polygon, in pixels. So this is my solution:

```
  var p = $('path[id^="OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon"]').attr('d').match(/(\d+\.\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)/),
  point = new OpenLayers.Pixel(parseInt(p[1]),parseInt(p[2]));
```

It's just a hack but hope it's helping.